# Refreshing JWT in Flask returns "Only access tokens are allowed"

Tags: authentication, flask, jwt, bearer-token

I have a strange problem with refreshing JWT token that I can't seem to find a solution for online.

My simple method for login:

```
@app.route("/api/login", methods=['POST'])
def app_login():
    json       = request.json
    form       = AppLoginForm.from_json(json)
    password   = json.get('password')
    mobile     = cleanup(json.get('mobile'))
    user_found = User.query.filter(and_(User.mobile == mobile, or_(User.user_type == UserType.dashboard_user.value, User.user_type == UserType.end_user.value, User.user_type == UserType.dashboard_and_end_user.value))).first()
    if user_found: #found
        if bc.check_password_hash(user_found.password, password):
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=user_found.mobile)
            refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user_found.mobile)
            return send_response(True, None, { "access_token":access_token,"refresh_token":refresh_token }, 200)
        else:
            return send_response(False,[messages.WRONG_PASS], None, 406, {"case":  UserLoginMeta.wrong_password.value})
```

My simple method for refreshing the JWT token:

```
@app.route('/api/refresh', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_refresh_token_required
def refresh_token():
    ''' refresh token endpoint '''
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return send_response(True,None, [{ "access_token":create_access_token(identity=current_user)}])
```

Calling it the normal way with refresh token fails, and calling it with access token also fails:

**Sending access token -> gives {"msg":"Only refresh tokens are allowed"}**

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.PkFwQfIwStFkt3pCkZK919H203rDpLOD-96kcNEcRHw" -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/refresh
```

**Sending refresh token -> gives {"msg":"Only access tokens are allowed"}**

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTAzNDczNDksIm5iZiI6MTYxMDM0NzM0OSwianRpIjoiNDQxNzViNDYtNDZmZi00ZDUxLThmYzQtZTYwNjY4ZDlmNTU1IiwiZXhwIjoxNjEyOTM5MzQ5LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6Ijk2NjU0MTgyMjY3OSIsInR5cGUiOiJyZWZyZXNoIn0.VdevyrbAJL78TwNrPIPlWnyiB3swCtbg9cLwCMvmU8w" -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/refresh
```

Why is that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause.

**I have implemented a handler method on `@app.before_request` and my logic was broken and it has overridden the normal behavior of refresh token.**

After I removed it, it worked Ok